# how to search dynamic table name to get table name from other table ID

Tags: sql-server, search

I have one table (Check) in my database and table fields are followed

```
ID   Start         End
1    2021-02-07    2021-02-15
2    2021-02-15    2021-02-24
3    2021-02-24    2021-02-30
4    2021-02-30    2021-03-07
5    2021-03-07    2021-03-14
6    2021-03-14    2021-03-19
7    2021-03-19    2021-03-27
8    2021-03-27    2021-04-03
9    2021-04-03    2021-04-11
```

and second, the dynamic table which is created dynamically when table rows reach 100000 records
table names are (Logs_1),(Logs_2),(Logs_3),(Logs_4),(Logs_5),(Logs_6),(Logs_7),(Logs_8),(Logs_9)
and soo on...these tables' first name is same but after underscore the numbers are generated from (check table) ID
logs_ fields are
Localtimestamp   and Timestamp
Now I wanna do is to write a search query to get date and time data reports from logs_.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why are you splitting the tables up when it gets to 100,000 **rows** (not "records") in the first place? A well designed database can handle tables with billions of rows, let alone 10's of thousands. this feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: It's a really bad design. You'll have to utilize a scripting language to dynamically write the sql to go after the tables you want, OR you''l have to just union every table together to query against the full record set. Either way it's going to be slow and painful working with this data. This should just be one big table, properly indexed, that you query once.

Comment: If you *really* need these log entries separated, for some reason, using a partitioned table would likely be a *far* better option.

Comment: this application and database structure is developed by a third-party company. we are using their application. now we want to create our own reports which are not available in the application.